# Ansible differentiate local and remote connection

Tags: ansible

We have lots of playbooks that we use to setup our remote instances. We would like to use those playbooks when bringing up our local environment for test purposes as well.

Is it possible to differentiate between a playbook running locally and remotely?

I'm looking for something like:

`- name: install apache2
   apt: name=apache2 update_cache=yes state=latest
   when: ansible.connection_type == 'local'`

Which means I only want to install apache when running ansible against my local environment.

I will then execute it with:
`ansible-playbook -i /root/ansible-config/ec2.py -c local myplaybook.yml`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is `ansible_connection` variable for every host.

Comment: I understand I can use that variable to configure the hosts, but will that be available for my playbook task?

Comment: Yes, you can use every variable inside a task, e.g.: `when: ansible_connection == 'local'`